# Recibir y almacenar una matriz de json en react

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, reactjs, jsonobject

tengo un pequeño problema, requiero recibir una matriz de json desde mi backend a mi frontend con react, almacentarlo en el state del component de la siguiente forma:

```
class getProjects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nom: JSON.parse(this.props.user),
      info: []
    }
  }
async componentDidMount() {
    this.getFolder();
  }
  getFolder = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('project/project', {
      project: this.state.nom.usuario
    })
    this.setState({
      info: [res.data]
    });
  }
}
```

Del lado del back end la respuesto que obtengo es una matriz de este estilo

```
{
    "archivos": [
        "Probando",
        "dddd"
    ]
}
```

Deseo obtener esa matriz para posteriormente mapearla y llenar una tabla con el contenido de la matriz. Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la respuesta de tu backend es:

```js
{
    "archivos": [
        "Probando",
        "dddd"
    ]
}
```

Entiendo que la lista que quieres setear en el estado es la contiene `archivos`?, para ello:

```js
getFolder = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('project/project', {
        project: this.state.nom.usuario
    });

    this.setState({ info: res.data.archivos });
}
```

Ojo, al no estar dentro de un try/catch o usar la promesa que devuelve axios, **estás perdiendo la captura de errores de la petición**, si algo falla en la petición, no estás controlandolo.